# Selecting specific namespaced content from an RSS feed using coreylib

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I am attempting to use [coreylib](https://github.com/collegeman/coreylib) to do some RSS feed parsing. So far, it has performed well enough for what I'm using it for (which is not bad, considering the only documentation I can find is what's on the github page...!)

Recently, however, I've run into problems parsing the [Metro News Toronto RSS feed](http://metronews.ca/feed/). When I try to parse the each `item` node to retrieve the text in its `title` node, I get the text in the `media:title` tag instead, since coreylib seems to ignore namespaces.

Is there any way to retrieve what I need (the actual `title` node!) from the feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, coreylib doesn't support namespaced XML feeds.

I bit the bullet and rewrote my entire parser using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).